# Tooltip in Highcharts doesn't show the right format for Date

Tags: highcharts

The tooltip in Highcharts shows the date as a long number.

[image]

Here is the link to the code: http://jsfiddle.net/np3tL24h/1/

I had the same issue with x-axis label showing these weird numbers instead of date and I used the formatter to format in the right way

```html
"format": "{value: %b '%y}"
```

I tried to do the same for the tooltip as well, but it is not working. I see from the highchart documentation to use xDateFormat for formatting the dates in tooltip. Here is an example from Highcharts where it is working as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/xdateformat/

I tried to do the same in my code as well, but it is not formatting the right way. I am using the following in my code:

```html
"tooltip": {"valueSuffix": "", "xDateFormat": "%b '%y"}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`headerFormat`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.headerFormat) like:

```
tooltip: {
    shared: true, 
    headerFormat: '{point.key:%b\'%y}<br/>'
}
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zysm24ty/